# CodeIgniter - can't delete particular cache

Tags: codeigniter

I have this model:

```
public function Vote($data) {
    $gameid = $this->input->post('gameid');
    $userid = $this->input->post('userid');
    $rate = $this->input->post('rate');

    $ins = array(
        'user_id' => $userid,
        'game_id' => $gameid,
        'rate' => $rate
    );

    $q = $this->db->insert('rates', $ins);

    $this->db->cache_delete('games',$gameid);
}
```

It inserts data and then it **should** clear the cache. But it's not - it does nothing. When I go with `cache_delete_all` it works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it insert the data?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, but not without a little shooting in the dark ;) My problem was the configuration for database. In `config/database.php` I had `$db['default']['cachedir'] = 'dbcache';`. Adding slash in the end helped!

Still, you have to remember to have your cache dir in root. Having it in, eg., `application` folder will also provide errors like mine.